# What markup does gwidgets glabel use in R?

Tags: r, user-interface, markdown, markup, gwidgets

In gWidget's glabel object there is an option to use markup in the label's text. I've activated this to true and tried to use a few markup conventions, e.g. for bold  ,  , ''' text ''' Markdown conventions etc. But none I've tried are working. Googling "Which markup code in gwidgets" did not help me either. I'd like to format some of my glabel text as bold and centralize other parts.

Comment: Could it be Pango markup ? http://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/PangoMarkupFormat.html

Comment: Depends, Pango is right for RGtk2, basic HTML in Qt, and nothing for tcltk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Depends, Pango is right for RGtk2, basic HTML in Qt, and nothing for tcltk.

jverzani hit the nail on the head, there is nothing for tcltk, which is the toolkit I am using on windows